# get a list of af:selectBooleanCheckbox adf

Tags: jsf, checkbox, oracle-adf

I have a few selectBooleanCheckboxes in a grid layout format. I would like to get a collection of these checkboxes: I don't want to bind them individually to a backing bean as they will be related to each other. Is there anyway to do this? Each checkbox is separate, but I would like to for instance get an ArrayList of these UI Components, and then figure out which of them is selected and which isn't. Maybe there is a group attribute I can use for this? Any help highly appreciated in this time-sensitive matter. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access their parent container (where your checkboxes are contained - for example panelGroup1 container -> getPanelGroup1()...) and access containers children via getChildren() (or something like that), and you should get all children (including your checkboxes). Probably you'll get more than checkboxes only , but you can loop throught all children and recognize your checkboxes. Also , it is possible that your checkboxes are deeper in hirerachy , but you can use same principle to access childrens children too.